# How to set keys for Pages using ValueKey?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am following this tutorial to add navigation to my app:
https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade

I don't understand how to create a key for a page.
I did some Googling. The error message that I get means that the argument must be a compile-time const, but it makes no sense.

The part in the tutorial that doesn't work for me, but works in the tutorial, because a list of books is compile-time const:

```
class BookDetailsPage extends Page {
  final Book book;

  BookDetailsPage({
    this.book,
  }) : super(key: ValueKey(book));
```

I don't want to hardcode a list of books, and I want the app to lookup a book by its book id. A user can provide an arbitrary book id.

```
class MyBookDetailsPage extends Page {
  final int bookId;

  const MyBookDetailsPage({@required this.bookId})
      : super(key: ValueKey(bookId));
```

But I get an error

```
lib/main.dart:311:20: Error: Constant expression expected.
Try inserting 'const'.
      : super(key: ValueKey(bookId));
                   ^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:311:20: Error: Constant evaluation error:
      : super(key: ValueKey(bookId));
                   ^
lib/main.dart:311:29: Context: The variable 'bookId' is not a constant, only constant expressions are allowed.
      : super(key: ValueKey(bookId));
                            ^
```

Adding `const` doesn't help.

There must be a lot about `ValueKey` that I don't understand.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter passed inside `ValueKey()` is same on rebuilding then the widget will not rebuild because Flutter now knows this widget has a tag.

```
children: <Widget>[
  if (showFirst) MyTextField(key: ValueKey(1),),
  MyTextField(key: ValueKey(2)),
],
```

Here we can see `ValueKey` takes a parameter which we have set to an integer 1, 2. We are free to choose anything as the parameter, but it shouldn’t change on rebuilding.

If you run these changes, the result looks something like this:

[image: This is how output looks]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still understand nothing. Do I need the parameter to change on rebuilding or not? What is a tag that you mention? Does flutter expect me to instantiate pages for each bookId in advance?
Typical use case: the user goes to /details/$id  (e.g. /details/345) and the page gets built with key ValueKey($id) (e.g. ValueKey(345)).